# Autoplay Doesn't Work

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm trying to disable autoplay for an audio file I have, but when I set autoplay to false, it still autoplays. Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

```
<audio id="player2" src="20130421.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls" autoplay="false"></audio>
```

Comment: take a look at http://wordpress.org/support/topic/autoplayfalse-preloadfalse-do-not-work

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you include the autoplay attribute, it does not matter what value you give it. It will always autoplay! To keep it from autoplaying, just remove it from the tag completely. If the audio tag never mentions autoplay, it will not autoplay. You can find more information about this at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/audio).

In conclusion, remove the attribute `autoplay` completely.